# Can't get the individual name of the files, but instead what was produced by the array?

Tags: java, selenium

I've been trying to write an automated uploader that will sort through a directory and upload the next file in the directory with each run. I read that I should first create a text file that will write the names of the files.

```
static String fileName;
static int i;

public static void incrementalChoice() throws IOException {
    FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter("fileNames.txt");
    PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(fileWriter);
    File[] fileArray = new File(pathToFiles).listFiles();
    try {
        while(i < fileArray.length) {
            fileName = fileArray.toString();
            printWriter.println(fileName);
            i++;
        }
        printWriter.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But every time I run it, the result of the text is the following list of files named like that.

```
[Ljava.io.File;@659a969b
[Ljava.io.File;@659a969b
[Ljava.io.File;@659a969b
[Ljava.io.File;@659a969b
[Ljava.io.File;@659a969b
```

Anyone knows how I can instead have the actual name of the file rather than that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are printing the array instead of a file hence it doesn't work.

Your code should be:

```
public static void incrementalChoice() throws IOException {
    FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter("fileNames.txt");
    PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(fileWriter);
    File[] fileArray = new File(pathToFiles).listFiles();
    try {
        for(File file : fileArray) {
            fileName = file.toString();
            printWriter.println(fileName);
        }
        printWriter.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

```

Comment: Awesome thanks! Both your and @Spock answers worked in their own way!

Answer (score 0):

You should, for each File of your fileArray, get the  Sring name of the File with getName().

```
while(i < fileArray.length) {
        fileName = fileArray[i].getName();
        printWriter.println(fileName);
        i++;
    }
```

If you want the file path, you can also call the method toString() directly on each File of your fileArray, (`fileArray[i].toString`) because the class File overrides the toString() method inherited by java.lang.Object and returns the path to file:
You get that result because you call the toString() on the fileArray, so for each iteration in the while the result is the same, and derives from the toString() definition in [Object](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html):

> public String toString()
>
> Returns a string representation of the object. In general, the toString method returns a string that "textually represents" this object. The result should be a concise but informative representation that is easy for a person to read. It is recommended that all subclasses override this method.
>
> The toString method for class Object returns a string consisting of the name of the class of which the object is an instance, the at-sign character `@', and the unsigned hexadecimal representation of the hash code of the object. In other words, this method returns a string equal to the value of:
>        getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())